# Symfony deserialize xml default namespace to object

Tags: php, xml, symfony, serialization, namespaces

Given are two xml files which have the same information in different format. Both should be deserialized into the same Symfony entity:

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<Request xmlns:dxn="http://defaultxmlnamespace.org" xmlns:axn="http://anotherxmlnamespace.org">
    <dxn:Id>123456</dxn:Id>
    <axn:Name>JohnDoe</axn:Name>
</Request>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<Request xmlns="http://defaultxmlnamespace.org" xmlns:axn="http://anotherxmlnamespace.org">
    <Id>123456</Id>
    <axn:Name>JohnDoe</axn:Name>
</Request>
```

In the first example, the namespace is registered with a prefix "dxn", while in the second one it is set as the default namespace. My Entity (without getter/setter) looks like:

```
private $dxnId;
private $axnName;
```

I use the "NameConverterInterface" to convert the node name from "dxn:Id" to "dxnId" as colons can't be used in an Entity element name. But this is not working in both cases, as the prefix "dxn" is known by the Serializer only in example no. 1.

My workaround is now to map the data to an array and manipulate it there before mapping it to the Entity. I think, saving the namespace in the Entity element name is not the best option, but I have to save the namespace information for later serialization.

So what is the best way to deserialize such a structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include JMSSerializer dependency to your project to manage serialization /deserialization of xml to entities if this is appropriate. It is really strong serialization tool that have special @XmlNamespace annotation with tag parameter which solves your case. Here are the link: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

Comment: Works perfectly and manages the namespaces exactly as I wanted to. It also solved my other problem, as with the JMSSerializer I can use other Entity field names than in the xml. Many thanks!